# Probability of not being included

Tags: self-study, sampling, coupon-collector-problem

Suppose that there are 100 buckets. Each time two balls are dropped into two buckets (i.e. they will never be dropped in the same bucket). I keep repeating the exercise.

Question is how many times do I need to do this exercise to say with 95% certainty that all the buckets would have been used atleast once.

Now I realise that for an individual bucket the probability of being empty after n iterations is $(1-p)^n$ where $p=0.02$ (from above) and $n$ is the number of iterations. However, I do not know how to extend this logic to 100 buckets.

Comment: Sounds to me like a [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).

Comment: This is a duplicate because dropping balls into buckets is exactly like collecting coupons in packets.